# n-dimensional generalization of Helmholtz decomposition

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $F$ is a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$. What can be said for the residual $B$ if $F$ is decomposed into

$$
F=\nabla \Phi + B
$$
for some scalar field $\Phi$? If not, are there any $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that makes $B$ special?

---

I found the answer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Generalization_to_higher_dimensions).
$$
\Phi(x)=\int F_\nu(x')\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\nu}G(x,x')dx'\quad\quad(1)
$$
and
$$
A_\alpha(x)=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}\epsilon_{\alpha\nu\sigma}\int F_\nu(x')\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\sigma}G(x,x')dx'\quad\quad(2)
$$
resulting in
$$
F_\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\Phi(x) + \epsilon_{\mu\rho\alpha}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\rho}A_\alpha(x). \quad\quad(3)
$$

The relation between $\Phi$ and $A_{\alpha}$ looks restrictive. Are they unique (up to a constant)? From $(3)$ it looks like I should be able to create a random $F$ from a random $\Phi$ and $A_{\alpha}$ (that are sufficiently smooth). Is it possible to show the following:

Any $C^1$ functions $\Phi$ and $A_\alpha$ can be modified to $\Phi(x)+c$ and $A_\alpha(x)+C_\alpha(x)$ where $\frac{\partial C_\alpha}{\partial x_\rho}=0$ in order to satisfy (1) and (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly weaker version of the decomposition in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that instead of $B$ being the curl of some vector field, you can require that $B$ is divergence-free. (It turns out that in $\mathbb{R}^3$, any smooth divergence-free vector field on a simply connected domain is the curl of some vector field) Taking the divergence of both sides of the desired decomposition and imposing this condition leads to solving a Poisson equation:

$$\nabla \cdot \nabla \Phi + \nabla \cdot B = \nabla\cdot F \implies \Delta \Phi = \nabla\cdot F$$

More generally, there's the Hodge decomposition, which works on $n$-dimensional smooth manifolds.